# Google Scripts: Make a button that will iterate the time in a cell by one hour

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, scripting

I've been struggling with this for a few hours now, and I still can't seem to get to get it right. I am trying to write a script for a Google Sheets macro that will look at a cell with a date/time in it, take that value and increment it by one hour.

Example: June 27, 2021 20:38:20, after pressing the button, the cell should show June 27, 2021 21:38:20.

I feel as is this is actually very simple and I know how to do it with a normal number, but the time and date formatting is giving me a lot of trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting to milliseconds works for me [see](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp):

```
function myDateInc()
{
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  r = sheet.getRange("A1")

  // Convert to mSec

  milliSeconds = r.getValue().getTime();

  // Add one hour

  milliSeconds += (60*60*1000)

  // Create a new date based on mSec

  d2 = new Date(milliSeconds);

  // Store date

  r.setValue(d2);

}
```